# local variable 'request' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, ajax, flask

So, here's my ajax call to a specific route in my flask app:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addfriend',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj.user),
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            $('#u-' + obj.user.id + '').css('background-color', 'grey');
            $('#u-' + obj.user.id + '').val('Pending');
        }
    })

}
```

So in my python code, here's the function:

```
@app.route('/addfriend', methods=['POST'])
def addFriend():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    data = json.loads(request.data)
    print data

    request = FriendRequests(sender_id=login_session['userid'],
                                recipient_id=data['id'])

    session.add(request)
    session.commit()

    response = make_response(json.dumps('Add Successful!'), 200)
    return response
```

but i get this error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment

This is the only route doing this. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `request` first.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/addfriend', methods=['POST'])
def addFriend():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    data = json.loads(request.data)
    print data
```

And you probably want to give you data object a different name.

```
    NOTrequest = FriendRequests(sender_id=login_session['userid'],
                                recipient_id=data['id'])
```

[Docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#the-request-object)